# Picasso library does not load image, android oreo 8.0

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, android-8.0-oreo

Picasso does not load image from url returned from Firebase realtime database, in Android `Oreo 8.0`, I am sure about that the url isn't null, because I've checked it through showing it in a toast!

```
final String value = dataSnapshot.getValue (String.class);
Picasso.get()
    .load(value)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_thumb)
    .error(R.drawable.failed_thumb)
    .into(imageDay);
Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true);
Toast.makeText (Dashboard.this, "Link: "+value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
```

Comment: Please, show a stacktrace with an error.

Comment: Ok, but let tell you i am not really sure about where the problem exists and where is the error in the log... because i am seeing every working fine... anyways let me put my log!

Comment: `01-27 02:35:42.832 3244-3368/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
01-27 02:35:49.356 3244-3870/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 200 [2019-01-27 02:35:49.356]
01-27 02:35:52.950 3244-3368/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
01-27 02:36:00.000 3244-3342/? E/AlarmManager: Set nextNonWakeup as mNextNonWakeupDeliveryTime=12449566 , orig nextNonWakeup=0
01-27 02:36:03.057 3244-3368/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1`

Comment: note it only causes trouble in oreo 8.0